# LINQ queries take more time to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my LINQ query and this is taking so long time to execute.
Can any one suggest me how to make it faster.
This query take almost 1.35 min to load.

From the list I am adding in model

```
var jobList = option.Equals("search")
        ? _jobService.SearchJobs(_dataModel.SearchFilter, _dataModel.CurrentPage - 1, _dataModel.EntriesPerPage,
            _dataModel.KeyWords, _dataModel.Location)
        : _jobService.BrowsJobs(_dataModel.BrowseFilterIds, _dataModel.CurrentPage - 1,
            _dataModel.EntriesPerPage);
    _dataModel.DbJobs = jobList;
    _dataModel.Jobs = jobList.Select(job => new JobsViewModel
    {
        JobId = job.JobId,
        JobTitle = job.JobTitle,
        SeoFriendlyJobTitle = job.JobTitle.ToSeoFriendly(),
        Created = job.Created,
        CreatedBy = job.CreatedBy,
        LocationName =
            job.LocationId != null
                ? _locationService.GetById((int)job.LocationId).LocationName
                : string.Empty,
        JobTypeName = _jobTypeService.GetById(job.JobTypeId).JobTypeName,
        RecruiterName =
            job.RecruiterId != new Guid()
                ? _recruiterService.GetById(job.RecruiterId).RecruiterName
                : string.Empty,
        SeoFriendlyRecruiterName =
            job.RecruiterId != new Guid()
                ? _recruiterService.GetById(job.RecruiterId).RecruiterName.ToSeoFriendly()
                : string.Empty,
        RecruiterId = job.RecruiterId,
        StartDate = job.StartDate,
        LocationDescription = job.LocationDescription,
        SalaryDescription = job.SalaryDescription,
        JobSummary = job.JobSummary,
        JobSummaryShort = job.JobSummaryShort,
        LogoPath = job.Logo.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? job.LogoOverride : job.Logo,
        PremiumJob = job.Advertising.Count > 0 && job.Advertising.ElementAt(0).PremiumListing,
        DaysRemaining = new Helpers().BuildDaysRemainingString(job.EndDate)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: The most obvious issue is that you're making four service calls within the `.Select()` expression. I hope those service calls are using a cache and not hitting the database.

Comment: no @DanWilson i am not using cache, implementing tomorrow but i thought from any other issue it getting time

Comment: You can break down the code into segments and use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to identify and target offending bottlenecks

Comment: some calls in jobList.Select maybe should be left join (use a new service), i.e. you called _recruiterService, I think this can be a left join in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Are those the service calls inside your query ? If so, most probably that is what  contributing to slowness.